# G Suite Admin API to access drive of all users

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer, google-workspace

I need to access all the files from the google drive account of all the **G Suite** user account from admin account.

Using `Google Apps Admin SDK`[`API`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list), I can access information of all account but unable to access their Drive.

I have seen admin can access google drive of all the users by admin console UI, but unable to find  API for same. I can access google drive from individuals access token with this [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list), but not of all users by admin token. Can anyone please help me into this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you must use Google Drive Api. You have to add the scope of your app inside security in the control panel.

With this you can autenticate has any user in the G Suite Domain and use the Google Drive as the user.

Here you can check more information about it https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth

Comment: than which API I should call,can u pls give me a link.

Comment: Inside security in the control panel, there are 6 section Basic,PasswordMonitoring,API ref ,SSO,Advance,SSL,Security& Privacy.None there have option to add scope,Am I missing some thing?can u pls tell me the path where to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this thread [Can the domain administrator see / edit all documents in Google Docs domain?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/AOvx-vpralQ/FiBchRN2cJYJ).

> No, the domain administrator can NOT see or edit any documents that you do not share with him or her. Google Docs are automatically private and you have to change the Share settings to invite the administrator as an owner, collaborator, or viewer.
>
> However, the administrator is able to go in to his domain control panel and reset your password to a new password that he or she knows. Then the administrator can log in as you and see and edit your documents. Keep in mind that any password you set is private. The administrator can only reset your password to another password that he or she knows. Of course, with any domain, you need to trust the administrator not to invade your privacy and they should have posted their terms of use and privacy policy for their domain.

You can find in this link the [Pre-built administrator roles](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986) wherein each role grants one or more privileges that together, allow performing a common business function.

Comment: I looked over the same,but the problem over here is to access any user file by admin password need to be reset,and there is no API to fetch users actual password,so when even admin accessing a file we have to update user by email that ur password has reset,so change your password.