# How to get all files of all users in organisation's Google Workspace using Google Drive API v3?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-workspace

How to get all files of all users in organisation's Google Workspace using  Google Drive API v3 ?

Could this be achieved by a single query e.g.

```
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            final FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH));
            final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(fileDataStoreFactory)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
            LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();

            final Credential credentials = AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");

            Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();

            FileList result = driveService.files().list()
                    .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                    .setPageSize(2)
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, size, mimeType, md5Checksum, sharedWithMeTime, ownedByMe, sharingUser, owners)")
                    .execute();
```

or should I do something like this:

```
get accounts list
    foreach account in accounts
        get drives from account
             foreach drive in drives 
                 get filelist from drive
```

Relating question [G Suite Admin API to access drive of all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571666/g-suite-admin-api-to-access-drive-of-all-users)

Comment: Yes, you should do something like that.

Comment: The second option, and do please post how you are building your `driveService` object.